# How do I use multidimensional jagged array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I am not familiar with multidimensional jagged array in C++. I am confused about how to use multidimensional jagged array in C++.
Consider following code:

> int** s=new int*[2];
>
> s[0]=new int[3];
>
> s[1]=new int[4];

Does the above statement means that I've declared array which has 2 rows & 1st row has 3 columns & 2nd row has 4 columns?
How to iterate through the array? Means that how can I display all elements of this array?
How to assign specific value to particular row & column. For example i want to assign value 9 to 1 row 2nd column. How can i do this?
Finally how can i deallocate the memory using delete operator?

Please help me. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. You don't use `new` in C++ for most of the use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the above statement means that I've declared array which has 2
>   rows & 1st row has 3 columns & 2nd row has 4 columns?

In this statement

```
int** s = new int*[2];
```

you declared an object of type `int **` and initialized it by the address of first element of a dynamically allocated array of two elements of type `int *`

> How to iterate through the array? Means that how can I display all
>   elements of this array?

You have to keep somewhere the number of elements in each one-dimensional array (row) allocated dynamically. For example you could have an additional array that contains these numbers.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 2;

    int size[N] = { 3, 4 };
    int **a = new int*[N];

    a[0] = new int[ size[0] ] { 1, 2, 3 }; 

    a[1] = new int[ size[1] ] { 4, 5, 6, 7 } ;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size[i]; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) delete [] a[i];
    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 7
```

Instead of the arrays you could use standard class `std::vector`.  For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 2;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    v.reserve( N );

    v.push_back( { 1, 2, 3 } );
    v.push_back( { 4, 5, 6, 7 } ) ;

    for ( const auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as shown above.

Comment: So, is there any difference between int **s= new *int[2]; and int **s=new int*[2]; Both are same? If not what is the difference? Please help me.

Comment: @ meet This record  int **s= new *int[2]; is simply invalid.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Is not `vector<vector<T>>` considered a bad idea because of too many redirections? There is no guarantee of contiguous memory location for the elements. I am not sure if this can be avoided using any other arthitecture though if one wants a jagged multidimensional array.

Comment: @Tryer  I see nothng bad.  There is no more redirections than for any two-dimensional array.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks. I agree that for a jagged array, `vector<vector<T>>` is possibly the best way. It is just that I have come across places where it is suggested to avoid it. If it is non jagged, and "full dimensional", with no holes, perhaps `boost::multi_array` is the option of choice. Would you agree?

Comment: @Tryer For a beginner the best solution is in the frames of the standard C++ features.:)